# salesforce php services errors

Tags: php, salesforce

I have a service that returns me when sending data

```
Element {}item invalid at this location
```

I get the session from another service and I attach it to it in headers

I show you my code if you can help me

```
$sforce_header = new SoapHeader("url_ser", "SessionHeader", array ("sessionId" => $loginResult->sessionId)); 

$cliente = new \SoapClient("wsdlservices.wsdl");
$cliente->__setSoapHeaders( $sforce_header );

$result['detalle']['CodigoProveedor'] = '2418';
$result['detalle']['EstadoInspeccion'] = 'Coordinada';
$result['detalle']['Fecha_Solicitud'] = '23/03/2021';
$result['detalle']['FechaInspeccion'] = '';
$result['detalle']['LinkDeConsulta'] = '<![CDATA[http://inspecciones]]>';
$result['detalle']['LugarInspeccion'] = 'Domicilio';
$result['detalle']['NumeroInspeccionProveedor'] = '1762387';
$result['detalle']['NumeroPropuesta'] = '';
$result['detalle']['Observacion'] = '';
$result['detalle']['ResultadoInspeccion'] = '';
$result['detalle']['Tipo_de_cliente'] = 'Persona natural';
$result['detalle']['TipoInspeccion'] = 'VEH';
$result['detalle']['Uso'] = 'Particular'; 
    
$resultado = $cliente->CreaInspeccionProveedor($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to send a valid request from Postman, SoapUI, curl or similar? It's hard to say, your snippet doesn't say what does it call (custom Apex class exposed as webservice? Standard SF SOAP API's "create" call? If standard - you'd probably need `__c` for all the custom fields). And I strongly suspect the date should be passed as 2021-03-21.

If you consumed a WSDL shouldn't you work with generated PHP classes and it'll magically craft right xml, escape special characters etc?

It's easier to work like https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm than with handmade requests like https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-soap-api-sample-wsdls.html